# How to trigger meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 popup programmatically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, meteorite

I am using [meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3](https://github.com/mangasocial/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3) for my meteor.js app. I have a button to trigger the login popup. I use the following code to add CSS class to `#login-dropdown-list`. The popup appears when I put the breakpoint after addClass statement. But It disappears after the function runs. I add `$('#login-username-or-email').focus();` but it doesn't work either. Is anything wrong here?

```
'click .login-btn': function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#login-dropdown-list').addClass('open');
    $('#login-username-or-email').focus();
  }
```

If I manually add a 'open' to `#login-dropdown-list`, It works. Is anything trigger a close event? For example, click on outside of the popup?

Thanks in advance.

Jake

Answer (score 4):

I came across this trying to resolve the same issue. The issue appears to be the "bubbling" of the 'click' event to the dropdown.

I was able to resolve it by replacing e.preventDefault() (which serves a different purpose in any case) with    **e.stopPropagation()**, which stops the bubbling. Also note that if you want to avoid jquery selectors altogether you can use      **Template._loginButtons.toggleDropdown();** Your example would then be something like:

```
'click .login-btn': function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    Template._loginButtons.toggleDropdown();
}
```

**-or-**

```
'click .login-btn': function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#login-dropdown-list').addClass('open');
    $('#login-username-or-email').focus();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. `Template._loginButtons.toggleDropdown()` works fine

Answer (score 1):

The way i see it there are two options:

```
$("#login-buttons .dropdown-toggle").dropdown("toggle");
```

and

```
$("#login-buttons").removeClass("open");
```

I know it's not a good way but unfortunately bootstrap doesn't provide us something like `dropdown("close")`. After digging into bootstrap's code i found that bootstrap exposes dropdown's constructor so we can do something like this.

```
$.fn.dropdown.Constructor.prototype.close = function() {
  this.parents(".dropdown").addClass("remove");
};

$.fn.dropdown.Constructor.prototype.open = function() {
  this.parents(".dropdown").addClass("open");
};
```

Then we can call:

```
$("#login-buttons .dropdown-toggle").dropdown("open");
$("#login-buttons .dropdown-toggle").dropdown("close");
```

At least it's in one place, so you can bind some events to it later.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply, I have tried all approaches you mentioned above. But none of them works. Even I put my breakpoint inside `'click .login-btn'` function, they can't open the popup programmatically. `$('#login-dropdown-list').addClass('open');` does open the popup, but the popup automatically disappears after the `'click .login-btn'` function completes. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Because we have a css class `.open > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}`, which `.open` must be the direct parent of `.dropdown-menu`, but I have no idea why it closes itself after the `'click .login-btn'` function completes.